# Deserialization of the XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a XML file which Looks like the following:

```
<xml>
    <classes>
        <class name="EventLog">
            <attribute name="TYPE" type="int"></attribute>
            <attribute name="DESCRIPTION" type="string"></attribute>
            <attribute name="ISSUEDBY" type="string></attribute>
            <attribute name="DATE" type="hr_clock"></attribute>
        </class>
        <class name="test">
            <attribute name="ttt" type="int"></attribute>
            <attribute name="ppp" type="string"></attribute>
            <attribute name="xxx" type="string"></attribute>
            <attribute name="aaa" type="hr_clock"></attribute>
        </class>
    </classes>
    <filters>
        <filter name="COILORDERFILTER">
            <attribute name="COILID" type="string"></attribute> 
            <attribute name="RELIABID" type="string"></attribute>   
        </filter>     
        <filter name="DriveDataFilter">
            <attribute name="DRIVEID" type="string"></attribute>        
        </filter>
    </filters>
</xml>
```

I need only the classes between the nodes `classes`. I created following classes for the deserialization:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("classes")]
public class ClassCollection
{
    [XmlArray("class")]
    [XmlArrayItem("attribute", typeof(SingleClass))]
    public SingleClass[] singleClass { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class SingleClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassCollection classes = null;
        string path = @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Eventlog.xml";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassCollection));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

        try
        {
            classes = (ClassCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException excep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excep.ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Can anybody say me "what is wrong"?

Comment: Is code throwing any exception

Comment: "what is wrong" you have to show us whats going wrong

Comment: At first impact, I'd say that you are trying to deserialize the classes nodes, but you give to the serializer the full xml

Comment: Note that you don't need the `Serializable` attributes for this kind of serialization... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392431/why-doesnt-the-xmlserializer-need-the-type-to-be-marked-serializable

Comment: Note: there is a missing closing quote here: `<attribute name="ISSUEDBY" type="string></attribute>` - you need to fix that before anything else

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tip; put your sample xml in a file - `my.xml`, say, then:

```
xsd my.xml
xsd my.xsd /classes
```

This creates `my.cs` which matches the xml.

Alternatively: you need to understand all the markup; the root  is `<xml/>`, so you need `[XmlRoot("xml")]`, for example. And you almost certainly mean:

```
    [XmlArray("classes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("class", typeof(SingleClass))]
    public SingleClass[] singleClass { get; set; }
```

This works, for example:

```
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class ClassCollection
{
    [XmlArray("classes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("class", typeof(SingleClass))]
    public SingleClass[] singleClass { get; set; }
}
public class SingleClass
{
    [XmlElement("attribute")]
    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Attribute {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem since there are no errors

but 1st:

```
[XmlRoot("classes")]
```

It means that the first XML node should be "classes" and it's "xml" right now from your example. So create a new object:

```
[XmlRoot("xml")]
class MyRoot {
    //...
```

Also, usually you'll want to have something like this as your first line for the default serializer to work I think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Also, I think you have some errors in your dataclass definition. You should comment some stuff and do some tests with less data in order to understand properly what's happening.

Comment: The "usually you'll want to have" is unnecessary - the xml description header is not compulsory

Comment: I remember having some issues with the XmlSerializer when I didn't have that header. I'm just writing that statement from memory but you're probably right and it's not mandatory. But I think it's a good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rework your xml, your question is very similar to this one:
[Ignore outer elements using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513955/ignore-outer-elements-using-xmlserializer)

Personnaly, I will use XmlReader instead of XmlSerializer to deserialize your sample XML because it allows to build a model that is not heavily coupled to the XML you are reading.