# How can I deserialize a XML file without defining the parent node?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I know there is a lot of content regarding deserialization of xml files, but I have not found a solution so far. My XML looks like this

```
<Data>
    <Products>
        <Product name="product1" brand="brand1">
            <ProductValues>
                <ProductValue name="price" value="100"/> 
                <ProductValue name="stock" value="23"/>
            </ProductValues>
        </Product>
        <Product name="product2" brand="brand1">
            <ProductValues>
                <ProductValue name="price" value="100"/> 
                <ProductValue name="stock" value="23"/>
            </ProductValues>
        </Product>
        <Product name="product2" brand="brand1">
            <ProductValues>
                <ProductValue name="price" value="100"/> 
                <ProductValue name="stock" value="23"/>
            </ProductValues>
        </Product>
    </Products>

    ... <!-- And more products -->

</Data>
```

I have a Product and ProductValue class where the corresponding fields are marked as `XmlAttribute`

```
public class Product
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string brand;
    public ProductValue[] ProductValues

    ... 
}
```

Everything works find, if I create a new class, which is called `Data` and has a field `public Product[] products` and I deserialize like this

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    Data data = (Data)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

I dont want to create an extra class for this and also not an extra field like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271442/deserializing-into-a-list-without-a-container-element-in-xml) but only instanitate the serializer with an array type `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product[]));` to receive a local `Product[]`. But if I do so, I get the error `<Data xmlns="> was not expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rand Random pointed out a possible dublicate, I looked at that question and finally git it working combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557145/9122672) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17514316/9122672).

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
reader.MoveToContent();
reader.ReadToDescendant("Products");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product[]), new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "Products" });

var products = (Product[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `XmlReader` with `using` to release the file handle.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Product> products = doc.Descendants("Product").Select(x => new Product() {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                brand = (string)x.Attribute("brand"),
                ProductValues = x.Descendants("ProductValue")
                    .GroupBy(y => (string)y.Attribute("name"), z => (string)z.Attribute("value"))
                    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> ProductValues { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ;) but I got it working.

Comment: Do you really need all the unnecessary class that serialization uses?  My code only uses one class.